# How to take difference between two linux time stamps

Tags: objective-c, linux, time

I have two linux timestamps begine-time and expire-time, i want to take difference between these two time stamps in hours, min sec.

> Language : Objective C
>
> "expire_time":"1366927200", "begin_time":"1327532400",

Comment: moderators why u give (-1) ? :(

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
int beginTime = 1327532400;
int expireTime = 1366927200;
int diff = expireTime - beginTime;

#define SEC_PER_MIN 60
#define SEC_PER_HOUR (SEC_PER_MIN * 60)
#define SEC_PER_DAY (SEC_PER_HOUR * 24)

int days = diff / SEC_PER_DAY;
diff -= days * SEC_PER_DAY;
int hours = diff / SEC_PER_HOUR;
diff -= hours * SEC_PER_HOUR;
int minutes = diff / SEC_PER_MIN;
diff -= minutes * SEC_PER_MIN;
int seconds = diff;

NSLog(@"%d d, %d h, %d m and %d s.", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
```